# Can see 100mbps in the lan even though i have cat6 cables and gigabit switch

Tags: windows, windows-xp, lan, gigabit-ethernet

I have a lan setup where i used cat 6 cable and a gigabit switch .. also the systems all have gigabit ports but lan connection speed only shows as 100mbps .. all the systems are running windows xp .. can some one please guide me as to what i need to do to get 1gbps.. ?

All the systems are close by.. nothing more that 10m apart.

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check...

Are the cables good?

Are all the systems and switch configured for auto-negotiation?

Are all the systems 100 or just some?

If all the systems are running at 100, I would bet you either don't have a gigabit switch or you don't have it configured correctly.

Comment: You can check for sure by forcing a gigabit connection under device manager. Another sure fire method.